# Getting "Invalid Client URI" in apache camel with azure-blob component

Tags: azure, apache-camel, cloud, jndi, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use azure-blob to download or get blob file from cloud.
As of now route is successfully started but expected blob file is not downloaded also java program is terminated immediately. Please suggest how to get the required blob file using **azure-blob**.

Below is the code used to get blob data from cloud using azure-blob

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageUri;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob;

public class RouteComposer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey("abcdefgh", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            StorageUri storageURI = new StorageUri(new java.net.URI("https://abcdefgh.blob.core.windows.net/abcdefgh"));
            CloudBlockBlob client = new CloudBlockBlob(storageURI, credentials);
            org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry registry = new org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry();
            System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.camel.util.jndi.CamelInitialContextFactory");
            registry.bind("clientreg", client);
            CamelContext mycontext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
            mycontext.setStreamCaching(true);
            mycontext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() {
                    from("azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=#clientreg&operation=getBlob")
                    .routeId("SampleRoute").to("file:c://output");
                }
            });
            mycontext.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please find below logs i am getting when i run above java program

```
19:21:19.409 [Camel Thread #0 - LRUCacheFactory] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.LRUCacheFactory - Warming up LRUCache ...
19:21:19.500 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Adding routes from builder: Routes: []
19:21:19.752 [Camel Thread #0 - LRUCacheFactory] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.LRUCacheFactory - Warming up LRUCache complete in 343 millis
19:21:19.906 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
19:21:19.906 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Using ClassResolver=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultClassResolver@7a187f14, PackageScanClassResolver=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver@6f195bc3, ApplicationContextClassLoader=null, RouteController=org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteController@51e2adc7
19:21:19.906 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - StreamCaching is enabled on CamelContext: camel-1
19:21:19.906 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
19:21:20.045 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Starting JMX agent on server: com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@2c039ac6
19:21:20.239 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=context,name="camel-1"
19:21:20.239 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.TimerListenerManager - Added TimerListener: org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedCamelContext@6ee12bac
19:21:20.239 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=health,name="camel-1"
19:21:20.249 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=routecontrollers,name="camel-1"
19:21:20.338 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultTypeConverter
19:21:20.350 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Found 3 packages with 19 @Converter classes to load
19:21:20.461 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/schintha/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001/camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
19:21:20.471 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/schintha/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-spring/2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001/camel-spring-2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
19:21:20.471 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/schintha/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-netty4/2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001/camel-netty4-2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
19:21:20.471 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/schintha/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-netty4-http/2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001/camel-netty4-http-2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
19:21:20.471 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loading file META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter to retrieve list of packages, from url: jar:file:/C:/Users/schintha/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-http-common/2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001/camel-http-common-2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001.jar!/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter
19:21:20.481 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Loaded 4 @Converter classes
19:21:20.504 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Type converters loaded (core: 194, classpath: 21)
19:21:20.504 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.ResolverHelper - Lookup Language with name simple in registry. Found: null
19:21:20.504 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.ResolverHelper - Lookup Language with name simple-language in registry. Found: null
19:21:20.534 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleLanguage - Simple language predicate/expression cache size: 1000
19:21:20.554 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultEndpointRegistry
19:21:20.574 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultExecutorServiceManager
19:21:20.574 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.SharedProducerServicePool - Starting service pool: org.apache.camel.impl.SharedProducerServicePool@2a798d51
19:21:20.574 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.SharedPollingConsumerServicePool - Starting service pool: org.apache.camel.impl.SharedPollingConsumerServicePool@6d763516
19:21:20.584 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultInflightRepository
19:21:20.594 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager
19:21:20.594 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultShutdownStrategy
19:21:20.604 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultRestRegistry
19:21:20.625 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultRuntimeCamelCatalog
19:21:20.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultTransformerRegistry
19:21:20.653 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultValidatorRegistry
19:21:20.676 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Using ComponentResolver: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver@33d512c1 to resolve component with name: azure-blob
19:21:20.676 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.ResolverHelper - Lookup Component with name azure-blob in registry. Found: null
19:21:20.676 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.ResolverHelper - Lookup Component with name azure-blob-component in registry. Found: null
19:21:20.676 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver - Found component: azure-blob via type: org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceComponent via: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/azure-blob
19:21:20.716 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=components,name="azure-blob"
19:21:20.716 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Cannot resolve property placeholders on component: org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceComponent@6025e1b6 as PropertiesComponent is not in use
19:21:20.744 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob], path=[abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm]
19:21:20.757 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob converted to endpoint: azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob by component: org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceComponent@6025e1b6
19:21:20.797 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=endpoints,name="azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm\?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob"
19:21:20.827 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Using ComponentResolver: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver@33d512c1 to resolve component with name: file
19:21:20.827 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.ResolverHelper - Lookup Component with name file in registry. Found: null
19:21:20.827 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.ResolverHelper - Lookup Component with name file-component in registry. Found: null
19:21:20.857 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponentResolver - Found component: file via type: org.apache.camel.component.file.FileComponent via: META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/file
19:21:20.878 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=components,name="file"
19:21:20.878 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Cannot resolve property placeholders on component: org.apache.camel.component.file.FileComponent@7c9d8e2 as PropertiesComponent is not in use
19:21:20.889 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent - Creating endpoint uri=[file://c://output], path=[c://output]
19:21:20.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - file://c://output converted to endpoint: file://c://output by component: org.apache.camel.component.file.FileComponent@7c9d8e2
19:21:20.929 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=endpoints,name="file://c://output"
19:21:20.949 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel - Initialize channel for target: 'To[file:c://output]'
19:21:20.959 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=tracer,name=BacklogTracer
19:21:20.980 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=tracer,name=BacklogDebugger
19:21:21.020 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=errorhandlers,name="DefaultErrorHandlerBuilder(ref:CamelDefaultErrorHandlerBuilder)"
19:21:21.040 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=services,name=DefaultStreamCachingStrategy
19:21:21.211 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy - Created spool directory: C:\Users\schintha\AppData\Local\Temp\camel\camel-tmp-fda3bb35-6967-4d27-818b-522670a70433
19:21:21.211 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy - StreamCaching configuration DefaultStreamCachingStrategy[spoolDirectory=C:\Users\schintha\AppData\Local\Temp\camel\camel-tmp-fda3bb35-6967-4d27-818b-522670a70433, spoolChiper=null, spoolThreshold=131072, spoolUsedHeapMemoryThreshold=0, bufferSize=4096, anySpoolRules=false]
19:21:21.211 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy - StreamCaching in use with spool directory: C:\Users\schintha\AppData\Local\Temp\camel\camel-tmp-fda3bb35-6967-4d27-818b-522670a70433 and rules: [Spool > 128K body size]
19:21:21.211 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.HeadersMapFactoryResolver - Creating default HeadersMapFactory
19:21:21.211 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Using HeadersMapFactory: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultHeadersMapFactory@6b8ca3c8
19:21:21.211 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Warming up route id: SampleRoute having autoStartup=true
19:21:21.211 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting services on route: SampleRoute
19:21:21.222 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: SampleRoute -> Channel[sendTo(file://c://output)]
19:21:21.242 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=producers,name=GenericFileProducer(0x53976f5c)
19:21:21.242 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache - Adding to producer cache with key: file://c://output for producer: Producer[file://c://output]
19:21:21.242 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: SampleRoute -> sendTo(file://c://output)
19:21:21.292 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=processors,name="to1"
19:21:21.292 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService - Starting child service on route: SampleRoute -> Channel[sendTo(file://c://output)]
19:21:21.320 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=routes,name="SampleRoute"
19:21:21.320 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.TimerListenerManager - Added TimerListener: org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedSuspendableRoute@2e55dd0c
19:21:21.322 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy - Load performance statistics disabled
19:21:21.322 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer - Starting producer: Producer[file://c://output]
19:21:21.322 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: SampleRoute >>> EventDrivenConsumerRoute[azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob -> Channel[sendTo(file://c://output)]]
19:21:21.322 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Starting consumer (order: 1000) on route: SampleRoute
19:21:21.322 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=consumers,name=BlobServiceConsumer(0x3d1cfad4)
19:21:21.343 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceConsumer - Starting consumer: Consumer[azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob]
19:21:21.363 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent - Registered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=threadpools,name="BlobServiceConsumer(0x3d1cfad4)"
19:21:21.363 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExecutorServiceManager - Created new ScheduledThreadPool for source: Consumer[azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob] with name: azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.SizedScheduledExecutorService@21282ed8[azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob]
19:21:21.363 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler - Scheduling poll (fixed delay) with initialDelay: 1000, delay: 500 (milliseconds) for: azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob
19:21:21.373 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: SampleRoute started and consuming from: azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&operation=getBlob
19:21:21.373 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
19:21:21.373 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.21.0.fuse-740039-redhat-00001 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.487 seconds
```

i am getting below error

```
19:00:50.189 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm] WARN org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceConsumer - Consumer Consumer[azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&fileDir=c%3A%2F%2Foutput&operation=getBlob] failed polling endpoint: azure-blob://abcdefgh/abcdefgh/test.rpm?azureBlobClient=%23clientreg&fileDir=c%3A%2F%2Foutput&operation=getBlob. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Invalid Client URI]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Client URI
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceUtil.getConfiguredClient(BlobServiceUtil.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceUtil.createBlockBlobClient(BlobServiceUtil.java:133)
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceUtil.getBlockBlob(BlobServiceUtil.java:66)
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceUtil.getBlob(BlobServiceUtil.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceConsumer.getBlob(BlobServiceConsumer.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceConsumer.poll(BlobServiceConsumer.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

program is terminating without downloading blob file.
Please suggest what and where i am missing
Adding JNDI tag to know if there is any JNDI error

Comment: Use `#azureBlobClient` so you refer to the actual name

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen , made changes as suggested and updated question.
Now i am getting below error
 `Failed to create route azure-route: Route(azure-route)[[From[azure-blob:/ABCDEFGH/ABCDEFGH/HELLO... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: azure-blob:///ABCDEFGH/ABCDEFGH/HELLO.txt?azureBlobClient=%23blobClient due to: No component found with scheme: azure-blob`

Comment: Make sure you have camel-azure-blob on the classpath

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen i have added required pom dependencies which i missed earlier given below , Now route is created successfully.
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-azure</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-azure-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: HELLO.txt Blob file is still not downloaded to local store "c://output"

Comment: 14:04:41.994 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.ResolverHelper - Lookup Language with name simple in registry. Found: null
14:04:41.996 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.util.ResolverHelper - Lookup Language with name simple-language in registry. Found: null
Could you please let me know if above log is an error and how to resolve it